# efficient way to extract conditional data by group from data.table, during non-equi join in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have two tables, one with time-series data (dat), and another with some reference points (pts), for a bunch of different observations (time.group and well). Please see minimum example tables:

```
set.seed(5)
dat = data.table ( time.group = c (rep ("base", 42), rep ("4h", 42)), 
                   well = c (rep ("A1", 20), rep ("B1", 22), rep ("A1", 19), rep ("B1", 23)),
                   frame = c(1:20, 1:22, 1:19, 1:23),
                   signal = runif (84, 0, 1) )

pts = data.table (time.group = c (rep ("base", 2), rep ("4h", 2)),
                  well = rep (c ("A1", "B1"), 2),
                  frame.start = c (3, 4, 3, 6),
                  frame.stop = c (17, 18, 12, 19) )

head (dat)
   time.group well frame    signal

1:       base   A1     1 0.2002145
2:       base   A1     2 0.6852186
3:       base   A1     3 0.9168758
4:       base   A1     4 0.2843995
5:       base   A1     5 0.1046501
6:       base   A1     6 0.7010575

head (pts)
   time.group well frame.start frame.stop
1:       base   A1           3         17
2:       base   B1           4         18
3:         4h   A1           3         12
4:         4h   B1           6         19
```

**I would like to extract the frame for each time.group and well, for which the signal is highest in the dat table, between frames of frame.start and frame.stop from the pts table**

**What is the most efficient way to do so**, as I have pretty large data sets with lots of time.groups and wells, and a few other "signal"-like data columns?

These are the strategies I have come up with so far:

**Example 1:** This works, but I feel that this is redundant/slow, as it essentially has to perform the "by" grouping twice:

```
dat [pts, .(time.group, well, frame = x.frame, signal), # returns dat's frame column (desired)
   on = .(time.group, well, frame >= frame.start, frame <= frame.stop) # non-equi join, groups once
 ][ ,
    .SD [which.max (signal), .(plus = frame)], # extracting frame at max (signal)
    by = .(time.group, well)] # groups again
>>>>>
   time.group well plus
1:       base   A1    9
2:       base   B1    8
3:         4h   A1   12
4:         4h   B1    8
```

**Example 2:** Here, I would get the right numbers if I added the i.plus column with the first frame column (-1), however I can't do that and it trips out because there are two columns named "frame" in the output after the join.

Also, it wouldn't work if frame didn't start from 1 for every group:

```
dat [pts,
       on = .(time.group, well, frame >= frame.start, frame <= frame.stop), # non-equi join
     .(i.plus = which.max (signal)), # if I add i.plus and the first column frame, -1, it gives what I want, but there are two columns named frame
     by = .EACHI
     ]
>>>>>>
   time.group well frame frame i.plus
1:       base   A1     3    17      7
2:       base   B1     4    18      5
3:         4h   A1     3    12     10
4:         4h   B1     6    19      3
```

**Example 3:** This also works and gives the same table from example 1, but just seems like lots of code:

```
tmp = 
dat [pts,
     on = .(time.group, well, frame >= frame.start, frame <= frame.stop),
     .(plus = .I [which.max (signal)] ), # returns row indeces from orginal data.table (dat)
     by = .EACHI][["plus"]] 

dat [tmp, .(time.group, well, plus = frame)] # extract from original table
```

**Example 4:** And this does not return the original frame column from dat, but returns the columns from pts, so I can't access the frame that corresponds to max (signal) in dat:

```
dat [pts,
       on = .(time.group, well, frame >= frame.start, frame <= frame.stop), # non-equi join
     .SD [which.max (signal) ], # does not return original frame column (x.frame), so I can't extract it
     by = .EACHI
     ]
>>>>>>>>
   time.group well frame frame    signal
1:       base   A1     3    17 0.9565001
2:       base   B1     4    18 0.9659641
3:         4h   A1     3    12 0.9758776
4:         4h   B1     6    19 0.9304595
```

I'm not sure if I should approach this from an entirely different angle and try to join pts into dat instead, I have no idea! Any insight into if there are more elegant ways of accomplishing this are greatly appreciated!

I'd also like to note that coming up with an optimal strategy to do this is pretty important, as I will be doing these types of data extractions many times, so I've been cracking my head about it for a while now :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
dat[pts, on = .(time.group, well, frame >= frame.start, frame <= frame.stop),
     .(plus = x.frame[which.max(signal)]),
     by = .EACHI]
#    time.group well frame frame plus
# 1:       base   A1     3    17    9
# 2:       base   B1     4    18    8
# 3:         4h   A1     3    12   12
# 4:         4h   B1     6    19    8
```

For some reason, using `frame` instead of `x.frame`, i.e., `frame[which.max(signal)]`, returns all `NA`, which I'd suppose is a *bug* .. Could you please [file an issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues) by linking to this post? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Arun, yes thank you! Will file a report. Is there a better way to remove the two frame columns besides chaining `[,!"frame"]` ? Also, just wanted to thank you for your work on data.table in general, its a real gem!

Comment: @JVP, glad. Thanks for your kind words. `by=.EACHI` returns all cols specified in `on` by default (since it's an implicit grouping operation on those cols), so you'll need to select required cols either as you did, or by reference.